# What language do they build other languages with?

Tags: java, c++, programming-languages

What language is used to build low level languages like c++ and java?

How could you build the first language with no language?

Comment: Java is a low-level language? Kids these days. :)

Comment: C++ is a low level language?

Comment: Maybe they mean low-level in terms of capability :)  OOPs! Here come the flames!

Comment: See also (the deceptively titled) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494372/how-can-the-linux-kernel-compile-itself

Comment: Good question. I couldn't answer it when a non-programmer friend asked me several years ago. Usually I imagine that java/c++ compilers are written in c, c compiler in assembly, assembly/machine language in hardward(digital logic). But in practice it's much more complicated.

Comment: Hey, how about punch cards? Is that low level?

Comment: Punched paper tape.  That's low-level.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How was the first compiler written?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1653649/how-was-the-first-compiler-written), [when-someone-writes-a-new-language-what-do-they-write-it-in](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629513/when-someone-writes-a-new-programming-language-what-do-they-write-it-in)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In the context of compilers, this operation is often called [bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_(compilers)). In particular, see the "Chicken and egg problem" section for a direct answer to your question.

The very *first* compiler would have been hand-written in assembly language. If your next question is "how was the first assembler written?" then the answer would be that the first assembler was hand-written in binary machine code, possibly with [front panel toggle switches](http://www.imsai.net/). This is undoubtedly a simplification of what really happened, but the concept is the same.

There is also an excellent article titled [Reflections on Trusting Trust](http://cm.bell-labs.com/who/ken/trust.html) by Ken Thompson about the risks of using a compiler for a language to build the compiler for that language.

Comment: +1 for mentioning Thompson paper alone. I believe that was his speech at getting the Turing award.

Comment: Also note that for new architectures, a cross-compiler can be built using a compiler from an existing architecture, that then runs on the existing architecture but generates code that runs on the new architecture.  That code itself may be a compiler than then runs on the new architecture.

Comment: "undoubtedly a simplification" not much of one really. Loaders came before assemblers.  Bootstrapping an assembler was the same deal as bootstrapping a compiler.  Simple to complex; adding a few features each time.  Mercifully, when I started 4 decades ago, most machines came with a sophisticated assembler pre-written by the vendor.  Even the lowly PDP-8.

Comment: "Bootstrapping an assembler was the same deal as bootstrapping a compiler. Simple to complex" Or, I suspect, just write the whole damn assembler in hand-constructed machine code. Which you could construct by hand-writing assembler, then hand-calculate the machine code one op at a time, then run it on its own source to make sure it gives the same result. I reckon an assembler can be simple enough to bootstrap in one step like this, especially if the assembly language doesn't have fripperies like named labels.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: Assemblers are actually painfully complex. Most assemblers have fancy macro facilities.  You don't want to write those in machine code.  Early assemblers were 2-pass -- 1 pass to gather symbols and then a pass of code generation.  That reflects the boot-strapping.  Code generation is first generation.  Symbol resolution is the add-on to code generation.  Macros are yet another add-on.

Answer (score 14):

You don't build a language, but you build a [compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler) or an [interpreter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreter_(computing)) ... and for this you can choose any language even the language you want to compile ...

> The first self-hosting compiler —
>   capable of compiling its own source
>   code in a high-level language — was
>   created for Lisp ... Since the 1970s
>   it has become common practice to
>   implement a compiler in the language
>   it compiles, although both Pascal and
>   C have been popular choices for
>   implementation language.
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiler

Comment: +1 for the most straightforward answer to the original question. the links are great.

Comment: This is even true for weird languages like BCX. (A BASIC to C compiler from way back) The source for the compiler was written in BCX.

Answer (score 6):

Much of this kind of thing is done in C.

The first C compiler was not written in C; it was PDP-11 assembler.
Other early C compilers have been written in various assembler languages.

But all subsequent C compilers actually are written in C, based on an early "Portable C Compiler".  Yes, it's circular.  But the version x compiler can be used to build the version x+1 compiler.

Comment: Are you sure the first C compiler wasn't written in C? (Or I suppose strictly, in "C with a few features missing"). I can't quite tell from this article: http://cm.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/who/dmr/chist.html, but Dennis Ritchie says that B was already self-hosted before he started developing it into C, and he specifically mentions self-hosting as a desirable feature. If he went back to PDP-11 assembler, rather than developing B gradually into early C, do you know why? The innovation of PCC wasn't that it was written in C, but that it cross-compiled well.

Comment: Good point.  My understanding was the B was the template for C; not that the B compiler was modified to create the C compiler.  However, it's entirely possible I have that completely wrong and the B compiler was morphed to create C.

Comment: @Steve Jessop: "Expert C Programming" by Peter van der Linden gives expln: "A typeless language proved to be unworkable when development switched in 1970 to the newly 
introduced PDP-11. This processor featured hardware support for datatypes of several different sizes, 
and the B language had no way to express this. Performance was also a problem...Ritchie capitalized on the more 
powerful PDP-11 to create "New B," which solved both problems, multiple datatypes, and 
performance. "New B"—the name quickly evolved to "C"—was compiled rather than interpreted, and 
it introduced a type system..."

Answer (score 4):

I think the key insight to your question is the notion of [boot-strapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29). The link will describe how a language can self-host.

It is relatively common in the Lisp community. e.g. Some university classes will use [Scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) to write a language subset (this is not a compiler class activity).

That said, many compilers are written in other languages. For example, [PUGS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pugs) (Perl 6) is written in Haskell. [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29) is available in C or Java (as [JRuby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JRuby)).

Answer (score 3):

there are a couple options, you can implement the entire language in a language available on the target host, like C or Ocaml, whatever it may be. Once you have that implementation, you can write a compiler / interpreter in the language itself, build it, and now the language runs itself. this process is called '[bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29)'.

Comment: but the question is how was the first language written?

Comment: It was written directly in assembler, which is code the processor understands natively.

Comment: Processors do not understand assembly language, they understand machine code. You still need a program called an an 'assembler' to create machine code from assembly code (although there is a one-to-one relationship between machine instruction and assembler mnemonic).  Originally you would have had to set memory addresses and content using binary switches or hex keypad, or burn them into a ROM.  However, when bootstrapping a new architecture these days, you'd use a cross-compiler or assembler running on an existing architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "no language". The central processing unit operates on a series of signals to which we refer as bits or ones and zeroes (technically, changes in the electrical current flow). In th 50s, coding was done directly in what the CPU could "understand" and the pace at which programming was done was up to around 20 assembler commands per day.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by the other posters, you can write a language in practically any language, and often one of the first programs written in a language is a compiler for the language itself.

However, there are some languages that were specially developed for writing computer languages - namely lex, yacc, flex, bison (updated versions of lex and yacc). These allow you to represent the lexical and grammatical specification of some languages (I believe LLR, or LALR) in a form that can be compiled into an efficient language recognizer.

You do still have to write other parts of the language compiler/interpreter yourself, i.e. semantic analysis, code generation.

See

http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/

Answer (score 0):

Typically another machine or another language is used to write the first assembler and the first compiler.

As long as a working computer and a working language is available, even if rather different, the problem can be solved in two steps.

1. Write target language *x* for computer *y* in language *z* on computer (urk) *a*.
2. Write target language *x* for computer *y* in language *x*. Now a single compile on *a* will produce a translator that can run on *y*, and the second compile can then be on *y* with a fully-bootstrapped system.

The problem becomes simpler if the languages or machines don't differ.

Bootstrapping can also be done incrementally, and perhaps this was more common 50 years ago.

- Write a more powerful virtual machine (perhaps a stack machine or something with strings) in machine code
- Now, writing in the VM's bytecode, write something closer to the language

Something like Forth might make a good intermediate step.